# Controlling the spacing between lines with \fontsize{}{}\selectfont

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I've searched a lot and couldn't find the answer to this one. My puzzle is the following:

I use the fix-cm package to change the fontsize of a small poster (letter sized actually) to announce a seminar. I use `\fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont` for the title of the talk and other sizes for the rest of the information. My pickle is: if the title is too long (and it usually is), then the margins are not large enough to contain it so it splits the title into two lines, **with a very narrow space between them**. That is what's annoying me. So the question is: how do I increase the space between the lines, considering the title is actually a single line as far as the compiler knows? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: The small distance may be caused by the small leading (32). Use a bigger leading if your title gets too long. (Also see @mbork's answer.)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, may I incorporate your suggestion in my answer or do you want to provide a better one;)?

Comment: @mbork Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A popular mistake is to say something like

```
{\fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont A long title, spanning two lines}

And now the text.
```

Due to the fact that the line spacing in (La)TeX is uniform across the paragraph, and that the settings at the *end* of the paragraph count, you should end the paragraph *before* resetting the font, either by an empty line, or by a `\par`, e.g.:

```
{\fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont A long title, spanning two lines\par}

And now the text.
```

*Edit:* as Marc van Dongen noticed in the comment, leading of 32 is also probably too small - you may try to increase it.  IMHO, a good rule of thumb is `leading = 1.2*font size` - 36pt in your case.

Comment: +1 If you alternated between `put \par before }` and `put % at end of the line` you could correctly answer a large proportion of questions here and on other TeX forums without ever actually looking at the question.