# Too much whitespace on the bottom: how to make it as much as that on the top?

Tags: margins, geometry

This is the code for the cover of my thesis:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=4cm, inner=4cm, marginparsep=0.7cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage,xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{indented}{mo}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
        {\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#2}}
        {\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#1}}
    }
    {\end{adjustwidth}}
\begin{document}
{\makeatletter\def\Gm@Dvratio{1:1}\makeatother
\begin{center}
\rule{2.5cm}{2cm} \\
{\fontsize{16pt}{2em}\selectfont
Università degli Studi di Milano-Bicocca \\[-.5em]
\hrulefill\par\noindent
Corso di Laurea in Matematica \\
}
\vskip0pt plus .75fil
{\fontsize{16pt}{2em}\selectfont Tesi di Laurea} \\
\vskip0pt plus 2fil
{\fontsize{30pt}{1em}\selectfont
Orbite periodiche \\[.5em]
di flussi Hamiltoniani \\[.5em]
su ipersuperfici convesse
}
\end{center}
\vskip0pt plus 2fil
{\fontsize{16pt}{1.5em}\selectfont
Candidato \\
MickG \\
Number \\
\setbox3\vbox{\fontsize{16pt}{1em}\selectfont A}
\setbox1\vbox{\fontsize{16pt}{1.5em}\selectfont Candidato \\
MickG \\
Number \\[-2.5\ht3]}
\vspace{-\ht1}
\dimen3=\textwidth
\advance\dimen3-5cm
\begin{indented}{\dimen3}[0cm]
Relatore \\
Prof. RP
\end{indented}
\vfil
\begin{center}
\hrulefill\par\noindent
\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\selectfont
Anno Accademico 2014-2015
\end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
} \hspace{0cm}\\\clearpage
}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\hspace{0cm}\\\clearpage
\end{document}
```

OK, the alignment of Relatore with Candidato could be done better with a tabular, but it works fine in the actual thesis and I don't really want to change the code. Anyway it's not the point here. What I cannot do is get the bottom margin to be the same as the top one. As you can see, there is far more whitespace on the bottom than on the top. How do I get Anno Accademico further down? Thinking it was due to `geometry`, I opened the code, and I found `\Gm@Dvratio`, so I tried setting it to `1:1` on the cover and leaving it `2:3` as normal on the other pages. But to no avail, as you can see here. So what is the right way to do this?

**Edit**

Whoops! Here is the image of the typeset code:

[image]

**Update**

It seems that parameter is completely useless: Tried making that `\def` global (i.e. removing the braces around it and the page) and no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the parameters to `geometry`, you can simply add

```
\enlargethispage{<length>}
```

before the page is shipped out. The picture has been produced with `6cm` instead of `<dimen>`:

```
\begin{center}
\rule{2.5cm}{2cm} \\
{\fontsize{16pt}{2em}\selectfont
Universit\`a degli Studi di Milano-Bicocca \\[-.5em]

[...]

Anno Accademico 2014-2015
\end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\enlargethispage{6cm}
} \hspace{0cm}\\\clearpage
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\hspace{0cm}\\\clearpage
```

[image]

Experiment on the values, maybe pairing this with some `\vspace*{-2cm}` or what you think best just after `\begin{center}`.

Remove all attempts to modify `geometry` internals.

<sub>Of course I skip over analyzing the code, which I find hilariously horrible. Can you see that the title has different spacing between the lines? I know why. Since I wrote an easy to use package that produces an output similar to the one you seem to want, but without the errors, I won't go into the details.</sub>

Here's an example with `frontespizio`:

```
% arara: frontespizio

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=4cm, inner=4cm, marginparsep=0.7cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}
\Margini{4cm}{2cm}{4cm}{2cm}
\Logo[2.5cm]{duck}
\Universita{Milano-Bicocca}
\Divisione{\mbox{}}
\Corso[Laurea]{Matematica}
\Titoletto{Tesi di Laurea}
\Titolo{Orbite periodiche \\ di flussi Hamiltoniani \\ su ipersuperfici convesse}
\Candidato[numero]{MickG}
\Relatore{Prof. RP}
\Annoaccademico{2014-2015}
\end{frontespizio}

% il resto della tesi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. Yes I did notice the spacing, and I was wondering why that happened.

Comment: @MickG Hint: when `\fontsize` is changed, `\par` should be ***before*** the closing brace bounding the scope of the size change.

Comment: I changed the `\\ `s in `30pt` to `\par\noindent`s and the line spacing issue seems to have vanished. I think I'll ask a separate question about this tomorrow. Goodnight :).

Comment: Two questions though: the parameters are entirely at my disposal, what would you change? And what is "hilariously horrible" save for the terrible way of aligning that part where the other answer wisely used a tabular, and perhaps the consisten use of forced linebreaks?

Comment: PS to the previous comment: I also added a `\par` just before the brace, as you said.

Comment: [Found it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103568/42315).

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=4cm, inner=4cm, marginparsep=0.7cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage,xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{indented}{mo}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
        {\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#2}}
        {\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#1}}
    }
    {\end{adjustwidth}}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\rule{2.5cm}{2cm} \par
{\fontsize{16pt}{2em}\selectfont
Università degli Studi di Milano-Bicocca \\[-.5em]
\hrulefill\par\noindent
Corso di Laurea in Matematica \par
}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

{\fontsize{16pt}{2em}\selectfont Tesi di Laurea\par} 

\vfill

{\fontsize{30pt}{1em}\selectfont
Orbite periodiche \\[.5em]
di flussi Hamiltoniani \\[.5em]
su ipersuperfici convesse
}
\end{center}

\vfill

{\fontsize{16pt}{1.5em}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\rule{5.5cm}{0pt}}l}
Candidato   & \\
MickG       & Relatore\\
Number      & Prof. RP
\end{tabular}
}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\hrule
\begin{center}
\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\selectfont
Anno Accademico 2014-2015
\end{center}    
\clearpage

\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Well, if this is a template, I'm sorry to say that it is too messy. I don't have time to go into details, but the above is what you currently need. I have added two `\vfill`s at the appropriate places and replaced some of the too-many `\\`s with `\par`s besides adding a `tabular` for the last part.

The main problem, though, was using spacing expressions like `\vskip0pt plus .75fil` which will of course interfere with the `\vfill` that you want. I replaced these with normal `\vspace` expressions.

Comment: Hm, this solves the problem. THough to make it compile I have to substitute the `\rule` with a `\hspace{5.5cm}`. But what is the change that solved the problem?

Comment: @MickG Please see my second paragraph in the answer.

Comment: Indeed, just realized the `\vfill`s were the key edit. Why do you think that happened?

Comment: Just turned the `fil`s to `fill`s and the result is the same as yours, more or less. What do you mean by «the `\vfill` that you want»?