# How to improve text readability on noisy, colorful background?

Tags: graphics, color, backgrounds

I have a noisy, colorful background, and I am writing text into it. The problem is that depending on the background color, part of the text is difficult to read. This is a TeXified question of [this other question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/29256) from graphicdesign.SE.

Here is (the same) [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMgye.png) (originally taken from [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NA6KLY6)). Now if I use this, as a background (`london3.png`) in the following MWE (thanks to suggestions from Christian Hupfer it is now much cleaner):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\includegraphics[
width=\paperwidth,
keepaspectratio%,
]{london3.png}}%
}}      
\newcommand{\fancytext}[1]{\textcolor{white}{\contour{black}{\textbf{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
\sffamily
\Huge
\vspace*{3cm}
\noindent\scalebox{3}{\fancytext{This is a longgg text which is difficult to read on this background.}}
\noindent\scalebox{3}{\fancytext{This s anothhhher long text which is difficult to read.}}  
\end{document}
```

Then I end up with something like this:

[image]

This is rather unpleasant. To improve this text, I would like to

1. apply a [semi-transparent background, as shown here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29260) **surrounding** the text (but keeping the vivid background otherwise); and
2. fix the g-h phenomenon.

Comment: Your 'MWE' is a little bit noisy too (;-) ), but the `Draft` stuff vanishes by using `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks to your comment, I have removed some noise.

Comment: `background` is tikz-related picture, `transparent` interferes with `tikz` opacity settings, so loading both can lead to problems

Comment: Apparently, that was necessary for the [photo caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251319/80509).

Comment: by the "g-h" phenomenon, i believe you mean the fact that the descenders of the"g" overlap the ascenders of the "h".  the easiest way i can think of doing that is to add a small bit of vertical space between the lines.  since that will push down the second line, it would probably be advisable to decrease the vertical space at the top.

Comment: @barbarabeeton actually my intentions would be to write multi-line paragraphs with correct spacing. However, the `\fancytext` macro does not allow linebreaks, perhaps because of limitations of the `contour` package.

Comment: in that case, you want to reset the baselines to accommodate the enlarged size of the text.  that's best done with `\fontsize ... \selectfont` (see [Controlling the spacing between lines with \fontsize{}{}\selectfont](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103566/579), remembering always to end the text with `\par` or a blank line.)

Comment: The transparency can be achieved with `tikz`, but the `contour` breaks actually

Comment: Using contoured text was the first suggestion (from the graphics design post) to improve readability. I find it *really* useful.

Answer (score 1):

A preliminary solution, working for the `transparency` so far only`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
  \includegraphics[%
  width=\paperwidth,
  keepaspectratio%,
  ]{london3.png}
}
% \textheight = 630pt %762pt
% \topmargin=-1.2cm
\oddsidemargin=-2.5cm

\newcommand{\fancytext}[1]{\textcolor{white}{\contour{black}{\textbf{#1}}}}
\backgroundsetup{contents={\BackgroundPic},position={0,0},placement=top,scale=1,angle=0,opacity=0.6}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\sffamily
\Huge
\vspace*{3cm}
\noindent\scalebox{3}{\fancytext{This is a longgg text which is difficult to read on this background.}}
 \vskip0.5\baselineskip
\noindent\scalebox{3}{\fancytext{This s anothhhher long text which is difficult to read.}}  
\end{document}
```

**Update**, but still not really nice

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
  \includegraphics[%
  width=\paperwidth,
  keepaspectratio%,
  ]{london3.png}
}
% \textheight = 630pt %762pt
% \topmargin=-1.2cm
\oddsidemargin=-2.5cm

\newcommand{\fancytext}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture} \node[gray,#1] (A) at (0,0) {\contour{black}{#2}};\end{tikzpicture}}
\backgroundsetup{contents={\BackgroundPic},position={0,0},placement=top,scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1.0}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\sffamily
\Huge
\vspace*{3cm}
\noindent\scalebox{3}{\protect\fancytext[opacity=0.3]{This is a longgg text which is difficult to read on this background.}}
\vskip0.5\baselineskip
\noindent\scalebox{3}{\fancytext[red,opacity=0.3]{This s anothhhher long text which is difficult to read.}}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still trying to attack the `g-h`-issue

Comment: I see here you added an opacity flag to the background. But I don't want a fade background. I would prefer a vivid background with lively (lovely) colors, which are opaque/transparent/shady only around the text.

Comment: @Matsmath: Sorry, I misread.

Comment: see my comment above.  (of course, i may have misunderstood exactly how the op interpreted the problem.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, I found it already too, using some `\vskip`, for example